# How can I efficiently check if records exists with sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

User scenario is like follows.

My application has list of companies. Each company has a unique number (phone number) assigned to it.

Using the API service from google, the application can fetch companies that could have been already registered to my application, or not registered to my application.

Therefore, from the API call, I want to remove companies that have been already registered by searching phone number from my application. Result from API call will be less than 20.

1. The least thoughtful way is to to check if the record with phone number exists by iterating through the API result, which will cost O(n) sql queries. (I am not sure if this wouldn't matter if the phone number column is indexed, and `n` is less than or equal to 20)
2. Use a single query that has `n` number of `or` comparisons, to fetch the companies with any one of phone number from API result, and "filter" out the ones by iterating through the query result.

Do you think the second method will eventually have to compare O(n^2) times in the worst case in "filtering" process?

What would be the best practice to solve this problem?

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 & ActiveRecord with  MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `field IN (n1, n2, n3)` and `field` is covered with index - then you will get `O(lgN)` complexity, and `M * O(lgN)` in first one (practically `M` makes no sense as long as you say there will only be less than 20 elements)

Comment: N is a total number of records in DB?

Comment: @user482594: not actually. It just a notation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Yeah, I know what that means, but I was confusing which one stands for which because you used `N` and `M`.

Comment: @user482594: probably I should have specified `O(lgN)` in both cases which is mathematically more correct